# Missing Typemap configuration automapper error when map into model class

Tags: c#, .net-core, json.net, automapper, asp.net-core-webapi

I have 2 classses like this

```
    public class ListOfBMTTeamMapping
    {
        public class TeamMapping
        {
            public List<TeamMappings> results { get; set; }
        }
        public class TeamMappings
        {
            public int id { get; set; }
            public string areaPath { get; set; }
            public string agileReleaseTrainName { get; set; }
            public string deliveryTeamName { get; set; }
            public string keyedInTeamCode { get; set; }
            public string deliveryTeamId { get; set; }
            public bool isDeleted { get; set; }
            public string modified { get; set; }
            public string modifiedBy { get; set; }


        }
    }
```

and next  one

```
    public class BmtAdoMapping
    {
        public int? Id { get; set; }
        public string AreaPath { get; set; }
        public string AgileReleaseTrainName { get; set; }
        public string DeliveryTeamName { get; set; }
        public string KeyedInTeamCode { get; set; }
        public string DeliveryTeamId { get; set; }
        public string IsDeleted { get; set; }
        public DateTime? Modified { get; set; }
        public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }
    }

Here is the first class is defined to deserialize a third party API data like this

{
  "results": [
    {
      "id": 6534,
      "areaPath": "rtyty",
      "agileReleaseTrainName": "rtyrty",
      "deliveryTeamName": "fggfhfg",
      "keyedInTeamCode": "vbnvbn",
      "deliveryTeamId": 3254,
      "isDeleted": false,
      "modified": "2019-03-27T09:31:50.4581912",
      "modifiedBy": "balassm"
    },
    {
      "id": 6536,
      "areaPath": "werwbvcbvcb",
      "agileReleaseTrainName": "vbvbv",
      "deliveryTeamName": "Aerere",
      "keyedInTeamCode": "GTer33",
      "deliveryTeamId": 3256,
      "isDeleted": false,
      "modified": "2019-03-27T09:31:50.4792922",
      "modifiedBy": "balassm"
    }
  ]
}
```

So here is my code

```
ListOfBMTTeamMapping.TeamMapping Results = new ListOfBMTTeamMapping.TeamMapping();
Results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ListOfBMTTeamMapping.TeamMapping>(responseBody);
List<BmtAdoMapping> bmt = new List<BmtAdoMapping>();
bmt = _mapper.Map<List<BmtAdoMapping>>(Results);
```

Everythnig working fine and Results variable getting deserialized data. But my second class which is actually
a model class for my entity framework and on trying to map into that model class, I am getting an error like this

```
**AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException:** 'Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.'

Mapping types:
Object -> List`1
System.Object -> System.Collections.Generic.List`1
[[EPMO_Toolset_API.common.BmtAdoMapping, EPMO-Toolset-API, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]
```

Here is my Automapper profile

```
    CreateMap<ListOfBMTTeamMapping, JsonBmtAdoMapping>();
        
    CreateMap<ListOfBMTTeamMapping.TeamMappings, JsonBmtAdoMapping>()
        .ForMember(dest => dest.AgileReleaseTrainName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.agileReleaseTrainName))
        .ForMember(dest => dest.AreaPath, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.areaPath))
        .ForMember(dest => dest.DeliveryTeamId, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.deliveryTeamId))
        .ForMember(dest => dest.DeliveryTeamName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.deliveryTeamName))
        .ForMember(dest => dest.IsDeleted, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.isDeleted))
        .ForMember(dest => dest.KeyedInTeamCode, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.keyedInTeamCode))
        .ForMember(dest => dest.Modified, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.modified))
        .ForMember(dest => dest.ModifiedBy, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.modifiedBy));
```

Comment: you are deserializing the json to a 'TeamMappings' class and that is only a single item, you should probably deserialize your json into 'ListOfBMTTeamMapping' type instead.

Comment: I am deserializing into list since in the child class its mentioned as List itself. And thus deserialization working without any error. The problem is in Mapping the two classes.